# C# team project set-up

Tags: c#, version-control, collaboration

Me and a couple classmates are going to start working on an asp website together. Is there a way for all of us to work on different machines and different parts of the site, then combine the code into a whole. I was reading about the differences between Website and web application but that doesn't seem to answer my question.That looks like it has to do with the way the code is handled ie; compiled, not compiled,  and I can't find anything on the interent about it either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use some form of version control to share the code, like a shared [Github](https://github.com/) repo. (The setup would be one person's account "owning" the repo, and the others' accounts having write access to it.) That is, if I'm guessing at your concern correctly. You should try to explain what you're trying to accomplish more clearly than "combine the code into a whole" and "I can't find anything on the internet, any suggestions?"

Comment: http://Programmers.stackexchange.com is better place for this question as you are seem to be asking about process of team development rather than something concrete about piece of code.

Comment: @millimoose how can I be more clear? We want to be able to go home and work seperately on the site so we dont have to use one persons computer for all the coding

Comment: If you end up going with git or Mercurial and want a free private repository, BitBucket has free repositories for 5 users.

Comment: @healix You could be more clear by not spending 50% of your question on tangents about things you looked at that aren't what you want. If you mention three different things (sharing code, the difference between a website and a webapp, and something about how code is compiled) in the question, it's confusing as to which one you want help with. It would've also helped to include what you just mentioned: "all I can think of right now is using one person's computer for all the coding" since that's relevant to your problem, while things that don't solve it aren't.

Comment: @millimoose thanks for the life lesson. i'll write that down

Comment: @millimoose you spent 50% of your answer telling me what was wrong about the phrasing of my question. Wasn't productive at all. one comment is more than enough. This is a place for questions

Comment: @healix Yes, I did. Because in the long run, writing better questions (by improving the signal-to-noise ratio) gets you better answers, quicker. I fail to see how that was not productive. I also fail to see what you're trying to accomplish by being defensive about the phrasing of your question, you're entirely free to [disregard](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disregard) my commentary without being snarky.

Comment: @millimoose where's the disregard button?

Comment: @healix Well, it's not the one that says "Add Comment", that's for sure.

Comment: touché millimoose, touché

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called Source Control. It's a way for all of you to work in the same project, different (or even the same!) files.

The one designed by Microsoft is called Team Foundation Server, and they are typically expensive for professional outlets, but Microsoft has something which should provide the level of service you need (way more features than you need, probably). The best part about it though is that it integrates seamlessly into Visual Studio. http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

Alternatively there are other free options, such as github, but they often require your software to obey certain rules (be open source, for instance). Check them out, too. https://github.com/

Comment: GitHub is just a site that hosts git repos. You don't need to be open source or pay just to use git yourself.

Comment: I can get TFS for free through my school so I'll prob try it out

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you wouldn't want to set up a server of your own to run from, but if you have the resources then by all means use TFS, SVN, git, or mercurial are the big named ones.

Comment: it would be good practice to set up our server

Comment: @healix Not really, setting up infrastructure (like a source control server) isn't really a development concern. In every non-small company I worked at this was something that the dev team didn't really do. It would be good practice insofar as deployment is still a useful skill for a developer to have, but you should probably invest your time into something that's more important for now.

Comment: @millimoose do you have anything good to say? Why so negative?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is Source Control. There are many different systems out there depending on your needs. See [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/), [git](http://git-scm.com/), or [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) to name a few.

If you're using Visual Studio and you want to use Subversion, I personally use [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/). There are many different plug-ins out there for this, so have a look and figure out what you want.

Note: You're kind of giving conflicting tags there. C# is ASP.Net. Asp classic is written (usually) in VB Script.

Comment: As Rob G mentioned, TFS is an option. But, for a small group I don't imagine you'd want to invest a lot of money into your SCM option.

Comment: Team Foundation Service is free for up to 5 users.

Comment: None of the tags is really relevant since the question isn't about a programming problem specific to C#, but tagging this question correctly right would require having known the answer.

Comment: We're using VS and TFS is free through school so that's what I'll try. Thanks for shedding some light.

Comment: @millimoose exactly, I didn't know how to tag it. I tried team but it wouldn't let me and I don't think that would've been appropriate anyway but everyone seemed to do ok despite the tags

Comment: @RobG - I had no idea! Good to know.